# Why is Scala saying it can’t see members of org.joda.time.Period?

Tags: scala, jodatime

I’m writing a Scala script which uses [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.0.

When I try to run my script, I get errors like this:

```
error: value weeks is not a member of object org.joda.time.Period
        case "w" => Some(Period.weeks(windowSpecNum))
```

I’m also getting the message for `Period.minutes`, `Period.hours`, and `Period.days`.

This is really strange because I’m having no problem using other Joda Time classes, and because this class works fine in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> Period.minutes(5)
res0: org.joda.time.Period = PT5M
```

I tried a few workarounds:

```
error: org.joda.time.Period does not have a constructor
        case "m" => Some(new Period().withMinutes(windowSpecNum))
```

and:

```
case "m" => Some(Minutes.minutes(windowSpecNum))
error: error while loading Minutes, Missing dependency 'class org.joda.convert.FromString', required by lib/joda-time-2.0.jar(org/joda/time/Minutes.class)
```

which makes no sense, as joda-convert-1.2.jar is in my classpath.

Just to make sure I wasn’t doing something dumb with types (I’m new to Scala) I tried this: `val p = Period.hours(5)` and got the same kind of error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, I tried a small script and when given the two jars as dependencies, it runs without any problem. Can you provide a minimal non-working example and the command you use to run it?

Answer (score 6):

As per [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scala-user/aM4LNwNksXQ), the problem may have been that your classpath did not include a Joda Time dependency named Joda Convert.

Comment: I have a vague memory that this was indeed the problem.

Comment: Could someone please translate that *answer* into something specific to Play please? I've read it numerous times as this question here is the only source of info on the problem I'm up against right now and yet I can't for the life of me understand what actually needs to happen to make code work (compile) under Play (2.5.x)

Comment: For anyone else reading this `"org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1"` in build.sbt is apparently not the fix you are looking for...