# Play 2.5.x -- object org.joda.time.Duration is not a value

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Compiler problem that doesn't appear to be simple to resolve. (Then again everything is easy once you know how...)

```
import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format._
import org.joda.time.convert._

val durationLabel = org.joda.time.Duration(duration).toPeriod()
```

Yet I get this error:

```
object org.joda.time.Duration is not a value
```

This question ask the same thing but it's fix doesn't help at all: [Object is not a value error in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079129/object-is-not-a-value-error-in-scala)

This question's answer doesn't appear to help either: [Why is Scala saying it can’t see members of org.joda.time.Period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619348/why-is-scala-saying-it-can-t-see-members-of-org-joda-time-period) nor does this one: [Type value plusHours is not a member of org.joda.time.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996921/type-value-plushours-is-not-a-member-of-org-joda-time-datetime) unless I'm being extremely dense.

I believe that jodatime is "built in" somehow as when I add the following to build.sbt

```
"org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1",
```

it does nothing -- no complaints and no new downloads even after a `clean`.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

`val durationLabel = new org.joda.time.Duration(duration).toPeriod()`

should work.

`object`s in Scala define single instances of a class

There's no corresponding construct in Java, so you'll need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate your instance of `Duration`.

Comment: Wow - another "blue fairy snorts the angel dust" scala style error I can finally understand and add to the bablefish translator :)  I'll presume that is what things like nscala-time attempt to address: https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Forgot to suggest to use `nscala-time`. Wasn't sure you wanted joda.